# Regex Pattern Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I will have the following possible strings:

12_3

or

12_3+14_1+16_3-400_2

The numbers could be different, but what I'm looking for are the X_X numeric patterns.  However, I need to do a replace that will search for 2_3 and NOT return the 12_3 as a valid match.

The +/-'s are arthemtic symbols, and can be any valid value.  They also ARENT required (in the example of the first) .. so, I might want to check a string that just has 12_3, and if I pass in 2_3, it would NOT return a match.  Only if I passed in 12_3.

This is for a C# script.

Many thanks for any help!! I'm regex stupid.

Comment: I don't understand the plethora of "questions" that are nothing more than requests for us to do your work for you. There are a large number of ways to learn Regular Expressions from reading great books like Mastering Regular Expressions or software such as RegEx Buddy. Either way there is no excuse for asking a Regular Expressions question without showing any expressions you've tried to craft first.

Comment: @Frazell - this is the fifth question by this user, and his/her first regex question. If you think there's a general problem please start a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but it's basically noise here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, we have ,i.e.:
2_3+12_3+14_1+16_3-400_2+2_3

regexp #1:

```
Regex r1 = new Regex(@"\d+(\d_\d)");
MatchCollection mc = r1.Matches(sourcestring);
```

Matches Found:

[0][0] = 12_3
[0][1] = 2_3

[1][0] = 14_1
[1][1] = 4_1

[2][0] = 16_3
[2][1] = 6_3

[3][0] = 400_2
[3][1] = 0_2

regexp #2:

```
Regex r2 = new Regex(@"\d+\d_\d");
MatchCollection mc = r2.Matches(sourcestring);
```

Matches Found:

[0][0] = 12_3

[1][0] = 14_1

[2][0] = 16_3

[3][0] = 400_2

Is here that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had a similar pattern to your second one, but I couldnt figure out if I needed to do multiple patterns based on the digit count on the left and right side of the _ ..  Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`\b\d+_\d+\b`.

`\d` is digit and `\b` is a zero-width word boundary.  See this [C# regex cheat sheet](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/csharp-regular-expression-operator-cheat-sheet/).

UPDATE: I just looked for a "C# regex cheat sheet" to verify that `\b` was a word boundary (it's `\<` and `\>` in grep).  That was the first result.  I didn't actually verify the text.  Anyway, I now link to a different cheat sheet.

Comment: See, I know what numbers I'm looking for.. So, for example, I know in my string I'll be looking for 2_3 .. So when I use the pattern \b2_3 ,  it finds the right "2_3" in the string 12_3+2_3+122_3 .. I don't really understand why, though?! :)

Comment: "Matches at the position between a word character" .. I'm guessing it sees 12_3 as a word, and the + as a delimiter?

Comment: Don't mind that cheat sheet. `\b` matches a position that's either followed by a word character and not preceded by one (start of word), or preceded by a word character and not followed by one (end of word).  The other character (if there is one) can be whitespace, punctuation, or any character that's not a "word character" (i.e., a letter or digit, or connecting punctuation like the underscore). `\b2_3` doesn't match `12_3` because the `\b` would have to match between the two word characters, `1` and `2`.

Comment: @extreme: If you know your numbers, you should be able to do this: `\b2_3\b`.